# Find all elements in dataframe column that startswith string

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently rolling up numbers with the following code.  For each element in the `dataframe`, I am setting a few conditions for which to sum by, but it is the slowest part of a report that has been created.  Is there a faster way to identify all the elements in the dataframe that start with a certain string?

```
for idx, eachRecord in attributionCalcDF.T.iteritems():        
   if (attributionCalcDF['SEC_ID'].ix[idx] == 0):

       currentGroup = lambda x:  str(x).startswith(attributionCalcDF['GROUP_LIST'].ix[idx])
       currentGroupArray = attributionCalcDF['GROUP_LIST'].map(currentGroup)

       attributionCalcDF['ROLLUP_DAILY_TIMING_IMPACT'].ix[idx] = (
                                                         attributionCalcDF['DAILY_TIMING_IMPACT'][(attributionCalcDF['SEC_ID'] != 0) & 
                                                        (currentGroupArray) & 
                                                        (attributionCalcDF['START_DATE'] == attributionCalcDF['START_DATE'].ix[idx])].sum())

       attributionCalcDF['ROLLUP_DAILY_STOCK_TO_GROUP_IMPACT'].ix[idx] = (
                                                         attributionCalcDF['DAILY_STOCK_TO_GROUP_IMPACT'][(attributionCalcDF['SEC_ID'] != 0) & 
                                                        (currentGroupArray) & 
                                                        (attributionCalcDF['START_DATE'] == attributionCalcDF['START_DATE'].ix[idx])].sum())
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably being hit hard by this part of the `currentGroup` function:

```
attributionCalcDF['GROUP_LIST'].ix[idx]
```

Try saving that to a temporary variable and using the temp variable inside `startswith`. I'm planning to add vectorized string functions to pandas soon, so that will be a big help in these cases, too.

Comment: Thank you much Wes.  Improved the time of this function by ~40%.  Vectorized string functions?...very much looking forward to it!